# Calculating home bias in trade

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade

I want to make a simple estimation of home bias in trade within the EU countries by using
aggregated data from CEPII dataset
Link: http://www.cepii.fr/CEPII/en/bdd_modele/bdd_modele_item.asp?id=8

I have two variables on trade flows from IMF
link: https://data.imf.org/?sk=9D6028D4-F14A-464C-A2F2-59B2CD424B85&sId=1390030341854

the first trade variable is reported by the exporter and the other
is reported from the importer.

In order to calculate home bias I need to know how much a EU country trade with itself (domestic trade), Thats my problem, these trade flows are for goods only and my question is: Is there a way for me to estimate domestic trade within a country or some dataset ?